# Laptop not responding after hibernating

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, hibernate

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo W510 and most everything works fine except when I close the laptop and it goes to sleep and I open it back up. The startup screen turns on and it looks normal, but the cursor doesn't blink on the password login. I can use my mouse but the keyboard doesn't respond at all. I haven't found many similar problems, but any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I saw something like that when I close my W510 lid, hook it to my Lenovo dock with 2 monitors, and then try to wake it up.   I had to reboot the computer completely to get it to work.  As long as I leave mine off the dock, it works fine for me so far.

Comment: What do you mean by your dock? Just having it plugged into AC?

Comment: can you switch to tty using ctrl+alt+F1? had a similar issue and killing/restarting lightdm allowed me to log back in without rebooting. The problem is it ends your logged in session so any programs etc. you had running get killed.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem??? The same thing is happening to my laptop, when I lock the computer (suspending my user session), and I leave the computer for some time (say 20-30min); when I come back the keyboard does not work and I need to restart the computer to get it working again. Also, I cannot switch to tty using ctrl+alt+F1 (I tried sooner today).

Comment: I actually just switched to Arch Linux because I couldn't fix this problem and I didn't have control over the variables that would allow me to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

check the swap partition amount using disk utility.
I recently read through a lot info regarding partition set up. 
I0 recall reading that if using a laptop or any form of Hibernation,
it is recommended that you set the "swap" partition to X2 your ram.
example: 4gb(4096MB) ram swap should be set to 8gb(8192MB)

-[QUOTE from this site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211150)-
"In short: If you hibernate, allow your RAM size plus 1 GB (for instance, if you persist with buying 8 gigs of RAM, have a 9 gig swap partition). If you don't hibernate, don't bother with swap. You can always change your mind later and add it if you start doing high-end scientific analysis. "

Comment: Okay I'll look into it. Also around every 2 or 3 hours it just freezes up without any error message and I need to reboot it. Any idea if that is connected to a similar issue?

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem (W510, new installation of 14.04, computer unresponsive after closing and opening the laptop).  The problem did indeed go away when I increased the swap space available to 1G + twice my RAM.  (I have plenty of hard drive space, so I erred on the side of a large swap space.)

To add a larger swap file, I followed the excellent instructions on this web page:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I don't think your answer applies here. Hibernating fails when your swap space is too small. The system will just boot like it was shutdown the next time you power it on. Here the system was successfully hibernated. The problem is that it doesn't wake up correctly.